# Problem with textbox inside updatepanel - not causing OnTextChanged event

Tags: asp.net, ajax, updatepanel

I have the following situation: I have a textbox inside an ajax updatepanel. Wherever the user types in the textbox I must display a message (different message that depends on the user typed data).

```
     <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtMyTexbox" runat="server" Width="500px" OnTextChanged="txtMyTexbox_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:TextBox>
            <br />
            <asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server" CssClass="errorMessage" Visible="false">Hello World</asp:Label>
         </ContentTemplate>
            <Triggers>
             <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="txtMyTexbox" />
            </Triggers>
      </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

In server side I have written the following at page load

```
ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this).RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(txtMyTexbox);
```

and the method like this

```
protected void txtMyTexbox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {           
            if (.....)
            {
                lblMessage.Visible = false;
            }
            else
            {
                lblMessage.Visible = true;
            }            
    }
```

My problem now is that: when the user types in the textbox it doesn't cause OnTextChanged event.

Am I missing something?

Comment: note : only when I hit 'Tab' or 'Enter' it causes OnTextChanged event

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure that your problem has anything to do with the `UpdatePanel`.

In fact, the `TextChanged` event doesn't fire *while typing*. It will only fire *after* the textbox loses focus. This happens directly if `AutoPostBack` is set to `True`, or when the next postback occurs. Please see the docs for the [AutoPostBack property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.autopostback.aspx) and the [TextChanged event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.textchanged.aspx).

Afaik, your best bet is probably to handle the keyup event in javascript.

Here's a simple jQuery example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(':text[id$=YourTextBox]').keyup(function() {
        if ($(this).val() === "your special value") {
            $('span[id$=YourLabel]').css('visibility', 'visible');
        }
        else {
            $('span[id$=YourLabel]').css('visibility', 'hidden');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Set the `EventName` property for your txtMyTexbox `AsyncPostBackTrigger` to TextChanged

```
<Triggers>             
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="txtMyTexbox" EventName="TextChanged" />            
</Triggers>
```

Other sugguestion:

Have you tried looking at the [AutoComplete](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/AutoComplete/AutoComplete.aspx) control that is part of the AjaxControlToolKit?  Its behaves the same way you want your solution to behave.

Answer (score 1):

its strnage to know that even after adding update panel / AsyncPostBackTrigger , TextBox ChangeEvent doesn't work properly. Some time its works and some times it not..Since its is Asychronous call, we need to some time refresh, or wait or unpredictable , Hopes microsoft will come up with competent one.. Below are easy way to check user name pretty good

------   Under Page_Load - aspx.cs  -----------------------

this.TextBox1.Attributes.Add("onKeyUp", "fnUNameSubmit(this);");

-------in aspx -add script ---------------------------------------

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

function fnUNameSubmit(urInput) {   
var inpt= urInput.value;
if (inpt.length > 21) { 
document.getElementById('<%= TextBox1.ClientID %>').style.backgroundColor = "green";
document.form1.submit();  // This is only trick we use here..
}
else {
document.getElementById('<%= TextBox1.ClientID %>').style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
  }
</script>
```

-------in aspx -add script ---------------------------------------

----------------aspx.cs -------------------
if (TextBox1.Text.Length > 21)
        {
            CheckUsrName();
            Label2.Text = "";
        }
        else
        {
            Label2.Text = "Length is less than 21";  //lets do some stuff..bla..bla
        }
------------------------------------------------- CheckUsername()

public void CheckUsrName()
    {

```
  Call dB values

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not be using RegisterAsyncPostBackControl for your TextBox.  That method is really only for use for controls that reside outside of UpdatePanels.  I would try removing that line of code and seeing what happens.

See this for more info:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.registerasyncpostbackcontrol.aspx

Comment: i removed that line of code. it doesn't make any change. thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

a workaround check textbox - causesvalidation property and set it to true

Answer (score 0):

The Control which id is used in AsyncPostBackTrigger must be outside the update Panel(that cause to fire the Async call) like this:

```
<tr>
    <td colspan="4"><asp:Label ID="lblEnter_Successfully"  Text="Enter Record SuccessFully" runat="server" Visible ="false" ForeColor ="Blue" Font-Size ="Larger" Font-Bold ="true"></asp:Label>
    </td>
</tr>                                           
</table>                
</ContentTemplate>

  <Triggers>
     <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID = "Button_Save" EventName ="Click"/>
  </Triggers>                       

</asp:UpdatePanel>
            <table>
              <tr>
                <td width = "472px" align ="right">             
                    <asp:Button ID="Button_Save" runat="server" Text="Save"  OnClientClick ="return URLValidation();"/>
                    <asp:Button ID="Button_Clear" runat="server" Text="Clear"/>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
```