# ASP.NET OnTextChanged not firing from inside an update panel

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel, textchanged

I am using an ASP.NET update panel to retrieve user info using the on TextChanged for the textbox, here is my code:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="up1" ChildrenAsTriggers="true">
<ContentTemplate>
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="loginEmail" Text="Email" 
        CssClass="textBoxes" OnTextChanged="userInfo" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:TextBox>
</ContentTemplate>
<Triggers>
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="loginEmail" EventName="TextChanged" />
</Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

and the code behind:

```
string url, emailInfo;
emailInfo = loginEmail.Text;
url = Membership.GetUserNameByEmail(emailInfo);

emailText.InnerText = "Email: " + emailInfo;
urlText.InnerText = "Webiste: http://www.Elwazefa.com/User/" + url ;
```

**the code wont fire on textchanged** but it wil,
on ButtonClick or PageLoad.

What is the problem?

Using ASP.NET 4.0

Comment: If you can't sum the question up adequately in the title... it's likely either too generals or lacks the appropriate level of troubleshooting. (In this case it's all missing most of the applicable context and adequate description of how it "doesn't work".)

Comment: Can you show your complete "userInfo" function?

Comment: TextChanged does not fire on every keystroke, if that's what you are after: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/826023/problem-with-textbox-inside-updatepanel-not-causing-ontextchanged-event and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009086/how-to-make-an-asp-net-textbox-fire-its-ontextchanged-event-fire-in-an-ajax-upd.

Comment: `ChildrenAsTriggers` is true by default, and you don't need to add a trigger for `loginEmail` when `ChildrenAsTriggers` is true. I take it these were debugging attempts.

Comment: @sq33G - yes i was trying to figure out the problem

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
<asp:TextBox AutoPostBack="true" OnTextChanged="thingId_TextChanged" ID="thingId" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

[AutoPostBack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.autopostback.aspx) on text-box will trigger post-back when the focus is lost from the text box. `TextChanged` event will be fired on any subsequent post-back (can be due to button-click or text box focus change). So you need to make certain

1. After text is changed, you are moving out of text-box
2. Whatever controls that you are change are part of update-panel (can be different update panel). If there are not part of any update panel then those changes won't get reflected on client side.

My guess is you are probably suffering from #2. You can use tool such as Fiddler (or Firebug on FireFox) to check if browser is firing AJAX (XHR) request when the focus is lost from the text-box.

Answer (score 4):

As @VinayC posted, `AutoPostBack` means that the page will postback to the server when your `TextBox` loses focus. No built-in event causes postback on every character added to a text input, and for good reason. `UpdatePanel` postbacks don't cause the page to flicker, but they can be just as heavy as a full postback.

If you want to work around this, you can give your textbox a *client* `onchanged` event handler, the JavaScript of which will be built from `Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference()`.

The *correct* solution would be to use an AJAX method call from your JavaScript code rather than an `UpdatePanel` partial postback in `onchanged`.