# ASP: ontextchanged not firing

Tags: asp.net, ajax, ascx

Note:  I am brand new at ASP.NET.  I'm actually going to training on Monday, but we have a hot project that required me to dive in and get done as much as I can.

I've got a textbox on my page, and I would like it to call an event on the server whenever it is changed.  I don't care if "changed" means changed and loses focus, or just whenever a keyup happens.  Either case will work.

The issue is that, for some reason, whenever I change my textbox and then remove focus, the server-side method is not getting called.  Viewing through the debugger in Chrome, I don't even see any sort of AJAX call being made that would inform the server that a textbox was changed.

My Code:

### ASCX File

```
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="tempTagBuilder" runat="server" 
                CssClass="depBuilder_tempTagBuilder" 
                ontextchanged="tempTagBuilder_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="True"></asp:TextBox>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

### ASCX.cs File

```
    //whenever the text is changed
    protected void tempTagBuilder_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Hit");
    }
```

Anyone have a good idea of what my issue might be?

### Update 1:

I got it working (somewhat).  I had to go into the updatepanel's properties and add the textchanged event to the triggers collection.  However, now whenever it sends the update it is emptying out the other textboxes on my page!

Comment: do you have something on the client side that is talking to your server side event? Your event as is won't return anything to your debugger in chrome, it's simply using VS built in debug logging. You would see that in VS output window while you're debugging. Have you tried to a  response.write("test") or something similar in your textchanged event so that it writes something out to your page?

Comment: @JeffTurner I am viewing this in the visual studio debugger.  I confirmed that it _is_ working, because when I first load the page the event fires, so I see the output "hit"

Comment: I see... the problem might be because you're in an updatepanel. If you move the textbox outside of the updatepanel does it work? I think you need a full postback for that even to fire.

Comment: this entry might help you with that... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/826023/problem-with-textbox-inside-updatepanel-not-causing-ontextchanged-event I've added an answer if that ends up helping you.

Comment: @JeffTurner No, I actually originally had it outside of an updatepanel, but then whenever the textbox changed it was actually POSTing the page, which refreshed it.  I need it to send the updates via AJAX.

Comment: it wasn't refreshing the page it was issuing a postback. If you have an code in your page_load that loads any data you need to make sure it's surrounded with if(!Page.IsPostBack){} so that code is only firing on non-postback scenarios. OnTextChanged event doesn't seem to play nice with updatepanels according to a little searching.

Comment: Okay I see by your update that you've got it working somewhat. good deal

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't fire because it's in an update panel most likely. Seems the updatepanel requires you to set a trigger for the event.

[Problem with textbox inside updatepanel - not causing OnTextChanged event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826023/problem-with-textbox-inside-updatepanel-not-causing-ontextchanged-event)